# How could all the GNOME keyboard shortcuts be removed in a script, in other words, NOT using gconf-editor?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome2

I am developing custom software on a RHEL system, which tightly locks down every user on the system. I have implemented my own lock screen through `dbus`, user screen lock (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) through `xbindkeys`, and that's pretty much all I want them to be able to do.

I have an installation script for root to perform but for now, unfortunately, for every user root creates he has to go to `gconf-editor` or through the `System->Keyboard Shortcuts->Disable, Disable, Disable,...` sequence.  Is there a way to run a command to remove all keyboard mappings for a user?  Maybe through  `gconftool-2`?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used Gnome2 in a while but if memory serves, the file you are looking for is

```
~/.gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/%gconf.xml
```

Deleting that file should remove all Gnome2 keybindings.

Comment: so far all I have is `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/accessilibility/keyboard` which seems to have any relation to a keyboard. I will try and disable a few mappings and see if it creates a file.

Comment: @jnbbender enabling mappings should create the file, not the other way around. This is definitely gnome2 not gnome3 right?

Comment: Yeah, it's creating directories and files with empty XML tags like a beast now.  Thanks for the input. I'll package up what it creates and ship it out with the rest of my delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two half-ideas which maybe combine to a whole (but I have no system ready to try it): I suspect that the settings go to the user's `~/.gconf` directory or similar? There is a global default on what goes into a new user's home directory, possibly `/etc/skel.d/`. It might be possible to put the "cleaned up" `.gconf` in there to have it installed for every new user.